# Minimum Access Policy Permissions to Encrypt VM in Azure

Tags: azure, encryption, permissions

I need to encrypt VMs in Azure. To do so, I've created a key vault and a service principal dedicated to encrypting VMs. I'm trying to understand what the minimum set of permissions (access policy) are to encrypt VMs when not using key encrypted keys.

[image: Azure access policy screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Minumim you need:

```
"keys": [
     "wrapKey"
],
"secrets": [
     "set"
]
```

You also need to enable KV for disk encryption.

PS. updated answer, was looking at the wrong template >..<